# Need jsp form to submit query to specific path

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I'm trying to setup a simple form in a jsp that will put a search query in the URL submitted.

This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="search/" method="get" onsubmit="this.action+=this.q.value.trim();return true">
   <input type="text" id="q">
   <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

This is in a jsp that's included on each page of my web app and it works when I'm at the root of the app. For example, if I initially load "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/" then type "123456" in the search form, it takes me to "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/search/123456", which is what I want. However, from that page, if I search again (for "654321" for example) it goes to "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/search/search/654321", which doesn't work for me. I need search/{query} to be appended to the root of the app's path no matter what page I may be on at the time.

I would like to avoid javascript if possible, I'm fine with JSTL though.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why you use += ? Can you try this.action+this.q.value.trim();return true

Comment: It doesn't work if I take the "=" out. It just takes me to "../search" without the query being put in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a full path to your action, start it with /. Note it will depend on your application context, you could use :

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search/"...
```

It will work in dev and also prod.

EDIT :

Path : search will try to load relative from current path so : http://domain.com/contact/search/
Path : /search will try to load relative from the domain so : http://domain.com/

With the context path above, it will work no matter if it change from dev to prod.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helps some, however as is it doesn't work since it just takes me to "localhost:8080/search/123456" rather than "localhost:8080/MyApp/search/123456". If I hard code my app's name like this: 

    <form action="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/MyApp/search/"...

Then it works like I want, I would just like to find a way not to hard code the app name in the action so that if/when the app's war is renamed or deployed with a different context, this functionality won't break.

Comment: I've updated the action 31min ago... made a mistake about it, have you the last one? Normally the ${} part must print your "MyApp".

Comment: I'm more in JSF, maybe there is some differences, for sure there is a way to get contact in EL, try this : ${pageContext.request.contextPath}